# How do I stop Topsy from spamming my site with those annoying trackbacks?

Tags: pingbacks

Every time I publish a post, Tospy adds their pingback to my post.

It's annoying, but I don't know how to stop it.

Any advice?

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea I am curious how blacklisting (my answer) is not a solution? In context of WordPress this is really how to deal with trackbacks that are being created, WP cannot really influence what some service on the Internet sends out.

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea I do not follow, which links? If you have an idea how to improve the answer by editing you can also do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `topsy.com/trackback` (or whatever they are using for those links now) to `Settings` > `Discussion` > `Comment Blacklist`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you marked their comments as spam? Akismet is supposed to learn from comments you mark as spam. Try that, it should start being marked as spam eventually.

Answer (score 1):

just unmark the allow pingback/trackback while adding the post..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Combating_Comment_Spam) is rather old but most of it is still relevant.